# Returning Values Between Object Classes

Tags: python

I am working on a project that generates customer objects with unique vehicle objects associated. Each vehicle object can have particular parts which an associated cost. I am trying to generate the cost of each item in a particular vehicle object, and total the cost for the customer for each vehicle. My code below:

```
import enum

# Enum classes for various components
class Color(enum.Enum):
    NOCOLOR = 99
    RED = 100
    BLUE = 101
    BLACK = 102
    SILVER = 103
    GREEN = 104
    YELLOW = 105

class HoodType(enum.Enum):
    REGULAR = 200
    SPORT = 201
    LIFTED = 202
    NONE = 203

class FenderType(enum.Enum):
    REGULAR = 300
    SPORT = 301
    CARBONFIBER = 302

class WheelType(enum.Enum):
    POWERDERCOATED = 400
    PAINTCOATED = 401
    CLEARCOATED = 402
    CHROMEPLATED = 403
    BAREPOLISH = 404

# component classes
class Hood:
    def __init__(self, hoodTypeParam, hoodColorParam, hoodCost):
        self.hoodType = hoodTypeParam
        self.hoodColor = hoodColorParam
        self.hoodCost = hoodCost

# func to get cost of component type
    def hoodCostFunc(self, hoodTypeParam, hoodCost):
        if hoodTypeParam == 200:
            self.hoodCost = 499.00
            return self.hoodcost
        elif hoodTypeParam == 201:
            self.hoodCost = 599.00
            return self.hoodcost
        elif hoodTypeParam == 202:
            self.hoodCost = 699.00
            return self.hoodCost
        elif hoodTypeParam == 203:
            self.hoodCost = 0
            return self.hoodcost

# tostring for printing results later
    def hoodToString(self):
        print(
            "Hood Specs: ",
            self.hoodType, '', self.hoodColor
        )


class Fender:
    def __init__(self, fenderTypeParam, fenderColorParam, fenderCost):
        self.fenderType = fenderTypeParam
        self.fenderColor = fenderColorParam
        self.fenderCost = fenderCost

    def fenderCostFunc(self, fenderTypeParam, fenderCost):
        if fenderTypeParam == 300:
            self.fenderCost = 100.00
            return
        elif fenderTypeParam == 301:
            self.fenderCost = 200.00
            return
        elif fenderTypeParam == 302:
            self.fenderCost = 1000.00
            return

    def fenderToString(self):
        print(
            "Fender Specs: ",
            self.fenderType, '', self.fenderColor
        )

class Doors:
    def __init__(self, doorsColorParam, doorsCost):
        self.doorsColor = doorsColorParam
        self.doorsCost = doorsCost

    def doorsToString(self):
        print(
            "Door Specs: ",
            self.doorsColor
        )

class Wheelset:
    def __init__(self, wheelTypeParam, wheelCost):
        self.wheelType = wheelTypeParam
        self.wheelCost = wheelCost

    def wheelCostFunc(self, wheelTypeParam, wheelCost):
        if (wheelTypeParam == 400) or (wheelTypeParam == 401) or (wheelTypeParam == 402) or (wheelTypeParam == 403) or (wheelTypeParam == 404):
            self.wheelCost = 1299.00
            return
        else:
            self.wheelCost = 0
            return

    def wheelsetToString(self):
        print(
            "Wheel Specs: ",
            self.wheelType
        )

class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, vehicleMakeParam, vehicleModelParam, vehicleYearParam, hoodTypeParam, hoodColorParam, hoodCost, fenderTypeParam, fenderColorParam, fenderCost, doorsColorParam, doorsCost, wheelTypeParam, wheelCost, vehicleTotalPrice):
        self.vehicleMake = vehicleMakeParam
        self.vehicleModel = vehicleModelParam
        self.vehicleYear = vehicleYearParam
        self.hood = Hood(hoodTypeParam, hoodColorParam, hoodCost)
        self.fender = Fender(fenderTypeParam, fenderColorParam, fenderCost)
        self.doors = Doors(doorsColorParam, doorsCost)
        self.wheels = Wheelset(wheelTypeParam, wheelCost)
        self.vehicleTotalPrice = vehicleTotalPrice

# run functions to get cost of components
    def vehiclePartsPriceFunc(self, hoodTypeParam, hoodCost, fenderTypeParam, fenderCost, wheelTypeParam, wheelCost):
        self.hoodCostFunc(hoodTypeParam, hoodCost)
        self.fenderCostFunc(fenderTypeParam, fenderCost)
        self.wheelCostFunc(wheelTypeParam, wheelCost)

# func to get total cost
    def vehicleTotalPriceFunc(self, hoodCost, fenderCost,doorsCost,wheelCost, totalCost):
        self.vehicleTotalPrice = hoodCost + fenderCost + doorsCost + wheelCost + totalCost
        return self.vehicleTotalPrice

    def vehicleToString(self):
        print(
            self.vehicleMake, '', self.vehicleModel, '', self.vehicleYear, '\n',
            self.hood.hoodToString(), '\n',
            self.fender.fenderToString(), '\n',
            self.doors.doorsToString(), '\n',
            self.wheels.wheelsetToString(), '\n',
            '$', self.vehicleTotalPrice
        )

class Address:
    def __init__(self, addressLine1Param, addressLine2Param, cityParam, stateParam, zipParam):
        self.addressLine1 = addressLine1Param
        self.addressLine2 = addressLine2Param
        self.city = cityParam
        self.state = stateParam
        self.zip = zipParam

    def addressToString(self):
        print(
            self.addressLine1, ' ', self.addressLine2, '\n',
            self.city, ' ', self.state, ' ', self.zip, '\n'
        )

class Customer:
    # establish blank list for storing vehicles
    vehicleList = []
    def __init__(self, firstNameParam, middleNameParam, lastNameParam, addressLine1Param, addressLine2Param, cityParam, stateParam, zipParam):
        self.name = firstNameParam + " " + middleNameParam + " " + lastNameParam
        self.address = Address(addressLine1Param, addressLine2Param, cityParam, stateParam, zipParam)

# add vehicle to list
    def addVehicle(self, vehicleParam):
        self.vehicleList.append(vehicleParam)

# print full results
    def customerToString(self):
        print(
            self.name, '\n',
            self.address.addressToString(), '\n'
        )
        for vehicleParam in self.vehicleList:
            print(vehicleParam.vehicleToString())


print("--Welcome to the OO Class Project--")

customer1 = Customer("x", "y", "z", "12345 Good Ave", "Number 1", "Hastings", "MN", "55022")
customer2 = Customer("a", "b", "c", "449 Apple Street", "", "Eagan", "MN", "55123")
customer1Vehicle = Vehicle("Tesla", "Model 3", "2019", HoodType.LIFTED, Color.SILVER, 0.00, FenderType.CARBONFIBER, Color.BLACK, 0.00, Color.BLACK, 599.00, WheelType.PAINTCOATED, 0.00, 0.00)

customer1.addVehicle(customer1Vehicle)

# testing
print(customer1)
print(customer1Vehicle)
print(customer1.vehicleList)

# testing (why do things not order correctly? Why are there 'Nones'? Why does total price not populate correctly?)
customer1.customerToString()
```

I must be missing something in getting the cost updated on the variable, because in my testing I've tried print(customer1Vehicle.Hood.hoodCost) in the past after running customer1Vehicle.Hood.hoodCostFunc(hoodType, hoodCost) to see if it updates the value..it does not. This iteration I attempted to pass hoodCost (and other costs) as 0.00 from when the vehicle object is instantiated, hoping that would work, but it did not. Here is an example of my output:

```
--Welcome to the OO Class Project--
<__main__.Customer object at 0x104e27d00>
<__main__.Vehicle object at 0x104e27e50>
[<__main__.Vehicle object at 0x104e27e50>]
12345 Good Ave   Number 1 
 Hastings   MN   55022 

x y z 
 None 

Hood Specs:  HoodType.LIFTED  Color.SILVER
Fender Specs:  FenderType.CARBONFIBER  Color.BLACK
Door Specs:  Color.BLACK
Wheel Specs:  WheelType.PAINTCOATED
Tesla  Model 3  2019 
 None 
 None 
 None 
 None 
 $ 0.0
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My other nit-pick questions are: how come the outputs do not print in the order that I specified in my toString functions? And why are there a bunch of 'None' outputs?

I also apologize for the big dump--disregard if not worth the question. Recently had wrist surgery and redoing a smaller snippet would take some time.

I really appreciate any guidance, feedback, direction, etc! Thanks much!

Comment: "when I test print, say, self.hoodCost" Where do you add this `print()`? Please show in your code. In fact, try to reduce your code down to the fewest lines which illustrate what you are asking about. You can create a new file and build a small example from the ground up to make your question more clear. You might even answer your own question while doing this. Also, I recommend that you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code.

Comment: My apologies--in my testing, I've tried print(customer1Vehicle.Hood.hoodCost) in the past after running customer1Vehicle.Hood.hoodCostFunc(hoodType, hoodCost) to see if it updates the value.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question to show this.